# Is it always true to presume that the logical and operator won't evaluate the second expression if the first one is false?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

```
int* ptr;
//ptr may points to any location(e.g. nullptr)
if(ptr != nullptr && *ptr != 1) {
  //A
} else {
  //B
}
```

so are the above codes always equivalent to the following ones?

```
if(ptr != nullptr) {
  if(*ptr != 1) {
    //A
  } else {
    //B
  }
} else {
  //B
}
```

I wonder if this rule a standard or implementation-defined, and is the first piece of code portable?

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed to short-circuit.

Comment: Yes, the C++ standard guarantees that logical operators short-circuit for integral types. Surely you could have Googled that.

Comment: Weird, there was a question on this yesterday.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that overloaded versions will **NOT** short-circuit, introducing unexpected semantics, so it's generally a bad idea to overload them.

Comment: thank you, I didn't come up with the word short-circuit.